# Are "pocket monsters" more than marketing for the west?

Tags: pokemon

The suffix "mono" is common in Japanese nouns. In the English version, "mon" is supposed to stand for "monster". Is this merely dubbing and marketing, or does the Japanese version intend it in the same way?

Comment: Quoth [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon#Name): "The name Pokémon is the romanized contraction of the Japanese brand Pocket Monsters (ポケットモンスター Poketto Monsutā)."

Comment: @amaranth then thats an answer

Comment: @amaranth I sniped you, sorry – didn't refresh the comments

Comment: What does the common "-mono" suffix mean in nouns?

Comment: @tobiasvl If I had been interested in writing an answer, I wouldn't have posted a comment.

Comment: @tobiasvl tabemono and ikimono means food and animal, tabeta and ikieru are verbs for eat and live, for example.

Comment: @amaranth Fair enough ;)

Comment: @aitchnyu FYI "mono" is the Japanese word for "thing."  Therefore tabemono == "thing to eat," ikimono == "thing that lives," etc.  Also, there are plenty of nouns that don't end in "mono," so this observation seems situational at best.

Comment: @Steve-O would you say that a Japanese speaker wouldn't parse Pokemon as "thing that is po...cketable"?

Comment: @aitchnyu Yes, I would say that a Japanese reader **would not** do that.  "Pokemon" (and the longer "Poketto Monsutaa", as seen in the images Tobiasvi posted) are written in Katakana - an alphabet generally reserved for foreign loanwords.  A Japanese reader would implicitly understand that these words are not Japanese in origin.  If these words were meant to be understood as Japanese words, they would be written in Hiragana or Kanji characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word "Pokémon" is the romanized contraction of ポケットモンスター, or "Poketto Monsutā".

Here's the Japanese box art for the original games, which clearly shows the full game titles:

[image]
[image]
[image]